# Правильность конвертирования в новый массив?

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста насколько правильна такая практика перебора в новый массив?
Задача: Получить данные из базы данных , пройтись и вернуть новый массив из объектов с value и label
( Для рендеринга в React Select )

```
const categoriesPossible:any[] = []
  useEffect(() => {
    GetAllCategories.map((tower:any) => {
      const newObject:SelectInterface = {
        value: "",
        label: ""
      }
      newObject.value = tower.id
      newObject.label = tower.name
      categoriesPossible.push(newObject)
    })

  }, [GetAllCategories])
```

Можно ли данный код по другому более универсально написать?

Answer (score 1):

Метод `.map` создает новый массив при переборе. Для подобных случаев использовать стоит или `.map`, или `.forEach` вместе с `.push`, как у вас. В общем, как-то так:

```js
const categoriesPossible = GetAllCategories.map(({ id, name }) => ({
 value: id,
 label: name,
}))
```

Если не знаком такой способ обозначения свойств объекта - он называется [деструктуризация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Еще рассмотрите возможность записать результат перебора в state-хук. Это поможет избежать повторной операции при ререндере компонента.